# FlutterError (No Material widget found. IconButton widgets require a Material widget ancestor

Tags: flutter

When I used

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      GroupAddPosts(groupType: widget.groupType),
                ),
              );
            },
```

to change page then I got this error `FlutterError (No Material widget found. IconButton widgets require a Material widget ancestor.`

But I had did added it, my IconButton has Center on above

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    String value;
    return _selected == "0"
        ? Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.photo,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => selectImage(),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'max: 9 photos',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

So, where has issues?

And I also set

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _selected = "0";
    });
  }
```

Still got error.... where has error step and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap it with **Scaffold** or **Material** widget.

```
Scaffold(body:Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.photo,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => selectImage(),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'max: 9 photos',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: I had use Scaffold on below,  And I tried to used `if (_selected == "0") { return Center() } else { return Scaffold() }`, still got error

Comment: I am not sure. But did you missed MaterialApp above the root?. You need to show more code, otherwise it's too difficult tell the solution.

Comment: I'd added  Material above the Center :)